# Get text before and after nth occurrence of hyphen

Tags: php

Question:

```
ABC-101-Description-text-1
ABC-2001-Description-text-with-more-text-2
ABC-20001-Some-more-Description-text-with-more-text-3
```

Could someone help me get all the text before the nth occurrence of the hyphen, so if I wanted ABC-20001 in one instance OR wanted everything after ABC-2001.

I understand that I need to use strstr or strpos but am unsure, would appreciate some assistance...

Comment: your string will be fixed or it will change runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already know 'n' below as an integer:

```
$parts = explode('-',$string,$n);
```

Let's take this string:

```
$string = "ABC-20001-Some-more-Description-text-with-more-text-3";
```

If you want what's before the 2nd hyphen:

```
$parts = explode('-',$string,$n+1); // n=2,
$parts[0] = 'ABC-20001';
$parts[1] = 'Some-more-Description-text-with-more-text-3';
```

Third example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php.